# Lua Debugger that can Attach to Process

Tags: lua

My company has a program that uses Lua embedded in its runtime, loading up `.lua` files from disk and executing functions defined in them repeatedly.

Is there a way to attach to the running process and set breakpoints in my `.lua` files? *(I'd accept either gdb-style command-line debugging as part of the Lua distribution, or perhaps a third-party IDE that provides Visual-Studio-like GUI breakpoints.)*

Or is what I'm asking for entirely nonsensical and impossible given the nature of the runtime loading up random files from disk?

**Edit**: Looks like it's not nonsensical, given that Lua's own [`debug.getinfo()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo) function can determine the source file for a given function, and [`debug.sethook()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.sethook) allows a callback for each new line of code entered. So, it's reasonable to load source code from disk and be able to tell when the interpreter is executing a particular line of code from that file. The question remains: how do I latch onto an existing process that has a Lua interpreter and inject my own trace function (which can then watch for file/line number pairs and pause execution)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an alternative I use after much searching. If you have an external executable that loads lua, I got this working in a few minutes. The op is very responsive, it has an interactive debugger which loads your code you can place debug points interactively. It doesn't have an editor, but I use scite or crimson editor and start the executable, one line in your main lua module enables the debugger.

http://www.cushy-code.com/grld/ - this link seems dead now

I've moved to [eclipse.org/ldt](https://eclipse.org/ldt/) it has an ide and integrated debugger, recommended

hth

Comment: I've moved to http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/ it has an ide and integrated debugger, recommended

Comment: The link above is dead.

Answer (score 11):

If you can modify the `.lua` files, you can insert the following call just before anything you need to debug:

```
require 'remdebug.engine'.start()
```

It starts the [RemDebug](http://www.keplerproject.org/remdebug/) Lua debugger engine and tries to connect to a controller. If it cannot connect, it will just continue running as normal. I did [some fixes](https://github.com/mkottman/remdebug) to the debugger engine, such as dealing with temporary variables, and my student is working on a debugger GUI (due next year).

In the meantime, you can try if [Lua Development Tools](https://eclipse.org/ldt/) works for you. It features a [debugger](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/Concepts/Debugger) similar to RemDebug, which should be possible to set up as follows:

```
require("debugger")(host, port, idekey)
```

Alternatively, you can use [SciTE-debug](http://scitedebug.luaforge.net/), which is an extension to the SciTE editor, and can serve as a controller to RemDebug. Just make sure you insert the call to `remdebug.engine.start` somewhere in your Lua code and insert this into the SciTE output window:

```
:debug.target=remote.lua
```

When you start your program, SciTE should show the source and current line.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda) editor for that. It allows you to attach to a running C++ application, after that it detects that you're running a Lua Interpreter within your C++ code and show your Lua source code, where you can add beakpoints and inspect variables as usual.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lua plugin for IntelliJ](https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home) has a working debugger with no special setup required other than pointing to your Lua interpreter.

Here's a screencast of it:

http://www.screencast.com/t/CBWIkoZPg

Comment: I can debug simple things this way, but I can't work out how to debug "busted" unit tests though. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Michal Kottman described, I have implemented a debugger based on RemDebug, but with additional fixes and features (on github: https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug).

You can update your .lua file with `require("mobdebug").start("localhost", 8171)` at the point where you want the debugging to start. You can then use the command line debugger to execute commands, set breakpoints, evaluate/execute expressions and so on.

As an alternative, you can use [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/), which integrates with the debugger and gives you a front-end to load your code and execute same debugger commands in a nice GUI. If you want to see the IDE in action, I have a simple demo here: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/live-coding-in-lua-bret-victor-style.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda).
Go to `Debug -> Processes -> Attach` to attach your process. This should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Well the easiest way is this, thanks to the genius author
https://github.com/slembcke/debugger.lua

you don't need to setup a remote debug server ,just require one file,and simplely call dbg() and it will pause,just like gdb

an tutorial is also shipped with it, check it out.